# JsonMappingException jackson getOriginalMessage is null

Tags: java, spring, exception, jackson

With my application (a spring boot java application), I get

`JsonMappingException location: [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 40]`

But `jsonMappingException.getOriginalMessage()` is null and I'm logging these two details. This happens when parsing the request sent by client.
Some of my clients are getting this error constantly while others never get it. For both sets of clients, the request is the same and I'm not able to reproduce it. Any insight?

Comment: provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the client request contains one attribute set as null which caused the error.